# Order status change turns not the same at different admin panels

Tags: php, prestashop, payment-gateway, prestashop-1.6

I process orders with custom payment gateway. (PS v1.6.1.6)
The gateway returns user browser to shop page (payment module front controler http://demo.site.com/module/latcard/paymentreturn) with http POST payload containing new order status id:

```
STATUS: ERROR
ERRORINFO: 981:ERROR 3D-secure
ORDER_ID: 66
AMOUNT: 45.99
```

I update (change status) order programmatically in the front controller this way:

### paymentreturn.php

```
public function _postProcess() {

    if (isset($_POST) && Tools::getValue('INDEX') == sha1( Tools::getValue('ORDER_ID') . Tools::getValue('AMOUNT') . Tools::getValue('DT'))) {
        if (Tools::getValue('STATUS') == 'ERROR') { 
            ...
            /*** calling update method ***/
            $new_status=15;
            //  change status directly in Order 
            $order = new Order(Tools::getValue('ORDER_ID'));
            $order->setCurrentState($new_status);

            // change status in OrderHistory
            $history = new OrderHistory(); 
            $history->changeIdOrderState($new_status, Tools::getValue('ORDER_ID'));  
        } 
       ...
 }
```

The problem is that if I change ONLY in OrderHisotry the status seems updated as shown at admin all orders page:
[image]

Yet when I open that order separately, **the status shown as it been before**:
[image]

If I ALSO change status at Order model/table then the order status is OK. Both *all orders panel* and *individual order page* show the same updated status.

I'm aware of the two db tables *orders* and *order_history*. Yet sometimes the

```
$order = new Order($order_id); 
$order->setCurrentState($new_status);
```

causes shop to show blank page (Error 500) for PS v1.6.1.7.  When I've turned on debug mode the error was *call to undefined instance Swift_Message::newInstance() in /home/vitpict/bstyle.lv/classes/Mail.php on line 179* - **why**?
The code there is the same as in v.1.6.1.6 ...

I've not found much on *setCurrentState()* order method... Any docs?

The [example code](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/221403-changing-order-status-vith-php/?p=1092186) teaches to update/change order status only in the OrderHistory class. 
Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

If you'll check the setCurrentState method code, there is:

```
 /** Set current order status
     * @param int $id_order_state
     * @param int $id_employee (/!\ not optional except for Webservice.
     */
    public function setCurrentState($id_order_state, $id_employee = 0)
```

pay attention on line **@param int $id_employee (/!\ not optional except for Webservice.**

Comment: ok **not optional except for Webservice**. But how about a payment gateway returning info data in http POST request to that controller? May I consider *the payment gateway* as a *webservice* requesting that method?